# Different images to be displayed according to screen size in jquery and .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

So, I have this code and I have been trying to get the images to change accordingly with the screen size. I want it to keep checking the screen size and changing relatively.

Here is the code:

```
 $(function(){

            $.mbBgndGallery.buildGallery({
                containment:"#home",
                timer:4600,
                effTimer:700,
                controls:"#controls",
                grayScale:false,
                shuffle:false,
                preserveWidth:false,
                effect:"slideLeft",
                effect:{enter:{left:"-100%",opacity:1},exit:{top:0,opacity:0}, enterTiming:"ease-in", exitTiming:"ease-in"},


                 images:[
                 "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-01.jpg",
                 "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-02.jpg",
                 "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-03.jpg",
                 "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-04.jpg",
                 "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-05.jpg"
                 ],

                onStart:function(){},
                onPause:function(){},
                onPlay:function(opt){},
                onChange:function(opt,idx){},
                onNext:function(opt){},
                onPrev:function(opt){}
            });


        });
```

and here is the code to check for the screen size:

```
  var width = $(window).width(); 

  $(window).resize(function () {     

    if (width > 800){
    }       else if (width <=800){
    }

    });
```

Whenever I paste the code for the images within the code for the screen size, it breaks. What gives?

PS. The path for the images to be viewed are located in a different folder path:

Window screen:

> images:[
>                    "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-01.jpg",
>                    "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-02.jpg",
>                    "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-03.jpg",
>                    "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-04.jpg",
>                    "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-05.jpg"
>                    ]

Phone Screen Images

> images:[
>                    "images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-01.jpg",
>                    "images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-02.jpg",
>                    "images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-03.jpg",
>                    "images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-04.jpg",
>                    "images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-05.jpg"
>                    ]

Comment: why not just use a [picture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) tag with the [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#attr-srcset) attribute?

Comment: @synj I guess OP wants the functionality of this jQuery plugin...

Comment: for starters check window size and pass in correct array before initializing plugin

Comment: I didn't think of using an array, let me see what I can do, the first answer given was very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs (https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.bgndGallery/wiki) describe a method here: `myGallery.changeGallery(array)`.

This allows you to change the gallery images at will - i.e on width change of your window...

So, inside of your window.resize method, you can call `changeGallery` and pass in the array of images for the screen size....

Comment: You are certainly on the right track - see the comment below from @wild-beard, they have posted a working fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply, your answer was very helpful. However, I believe I did something wrong as I broke everything...

**This is the latest update on the code**

I have added the *$(window).resize(function() {..})* to the *$(function() {..})* with *myGallery*, images are still no where to be seen. The myGallery was previous defined as *$.mbBgndGallery.buildGallery* before I changed it.

This is what it looks now:

```
  $(function(){

    myGallery = new mbBgndGallery({
            containment:"#home",
            timer:4600,
            effTimer:700,
            controls:"#controls",
            grayScale:false,
            shuffle:false,
            preserveWidth:false,
            effect:"slideLeft",
            effect:{enter:{left:"-100%",opacity:1},exit:{top:0,opacity:0}, enterTiming:"ease-in", exitTiming:"ease-in"},

            // If your server allow directory listing you can use:
            // (however this doesn't work locally on your computer)

            //folderPath:"testImage/",

            // else:

             images:[
             "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-01.jpg",
             "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-02.jpg",
             "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-03.jpg",
             "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-04.jpg",
             "images/bb/Slider/slider-image-05.jpg"
             ],

            onStart:function(){},
            onPause:function(){},
            onPlay:function(opt){},
            onChange:function(opt,idx){},
            onNext:function(opt){},
            onPrev:function(opt){}
        });

    $(window).resize(function () {     

        var width = $(window).width(); 

        if (width > 800){

            var windowarray=[“images/bb/Slider/slider-image-01.jpg”,“images/bb/Slider/slider-image-02.jpg”,“images/bb/Slider/slider-image-03.jpg”,“images/bb/Slider/slider-image-04.jpg”,“images/bb/Slider/slider-image-05.jpg”];

        myGallery.changeGallery(windowarray);
    }
        else if (width <=800){

            var phonearray=[“images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-01.jpg”,“images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-02.jpg”,“images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-03.jpg”,“images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-04.jpg”,“images/bb/phoneslider/slider-image-05.jpg”];

        myGallery.changeGallery(phonearray);
    }

    });

    });
```

Of course I did it wrong since I never replaced the images within the function. I appologize for these noobie mistake, I am very new.

Comment: You need to define `var width = $(window).width()` within the `$(window).resize()` function. Defining it outside gets the width BEFORE the resize occurs and never updates it within the resize.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help! I placed the `var width` within the `function`; however, the images still are not displaying, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are attempting to use `myGallery` out of scope in your window resize function. `myGallery` is being defined in `$(function() {..})`. You would need to move your `$(window).resize(function() {..})` code inside the scope `myGallery` resides in. If you look at your debugger before any changes you may see that `myGallery is not defined`

Comment: I have added the `$(window).resize(function() {..})` to the `$(function() {..})` with `myGallery`, images are still no where to be seen .-. the `myGallery` was previous defined as `$.mbBgndGallery.buildGallery` before I changed it. Could this be the reason why the images are not showing? Or is it because of the defined `images[]` within the `function` itself?

Comment: I have updated my *answer* with the updated code.
The images to the *windowarray* are now showing; however, the images to the *phonearray* are not when resizing the screen

Comment: The images are only being display when I change the `myGallery = new mbBgndGallery` back to `$.mbBgndGallery.buildGallery`
However, how am I to add the if statement with the window.resize if i keep the `$.mbBgndGallery.buildGallery`

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the line of code. Yes, it is what I am looking for, the images now show; however, when the screen size changes, the images don't; they remain the same images meant for the desktop screen. I am still working on it..

Comment: Hey, update, I had a friend look at the code after several updates and referring to the code you sent previously. He also didn't see anything wrong with it. I guess I'll find another way to fix it. Thank you for all your help!